# Powershell Regex question. Escape parenthesis

Tags: regex, powershell

Been beating my head around this one all day and I'm getting close but not quite getting there. I have a small subset of my much larger script for just the regex part. Here is the script so far:

```
  
  $CCI_ID = @(
  "003417 AR-2.1"
  "003425 AR-2.9"
  "003392 AP-1.12"
  "009012 APP-1(21).1"
  )


  [regex]::matches($CCI_ID, '(\d{1,})|([a-zA-Z]{2}[-][\d][\(?\){0,1}[.][\d]{1,})') | 
      ForEach-Object {
        if($_.Groups[1].Value.length -gt 0){
          write-host $('CCI-' + $_.Groups[1].Value.trim())}
        else{$_.Groups[2].Value.trim()}
      }  

CCI-003417
AR-2.1
CCI-003425
AR-2.9
CCI-003392
AP-1.12
CCI-009012
PP-1(21
CCI-1


The output is correct for all but the last one. It should be:
      
      CCI-009012
      APP-1(21).1

Thanks for any advice.
```

Comment: As an aside: If you pass an _array_  as the first argument (the input string) to `[regex]::Matches()`, PowerShell will implicitly _stringify_ it, i.e. it will convert it to a single string comprising the (stringified) array elements separated _with a space char._ each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of describing and quantifying the (optional) opening and closing parenthesis separately, group them together and then make *the whole group* optional:

```
(?:\(\d+\))?
```

The whole pattern thus ends up looking like:

```
[regex]::Matches($CCI_ID, '(\d{1,})|([a-zA-Z]{2,3}[-][\d](?:\(\d+\))?[.][\d]{1,})')
```

Answer (score 1):

As you experiencing here, [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) expressions might become very complex and unreadable.
Therefore it is often an good idea to view your problem from two different angles:

- Try **matching** the part(s) **you want**, or
- Try **matching** the part(s) **you *don't* want**

In your case it is probably easier to match the part that you don't want: the delimiter, *the space*, and split your string upon that, which is apparently want to achieve:

```
$CCI_ID | Foreach-Object {
    $Split = $_ -Split '\s+', 2
    'CCI-' + $Split[0]
    $Split[1]
}
```

**`$_ -Split '\s+', 2`**, Splits the concerned string based on 1 or more white-spaces (where you might also consider a literal space: `-Split ' '`). The `, 2` will prevent the the string to split in more than 2 parts. Meaning that the second part will not be further split even if it contains a spaces.

Comment: This was an excellent answer and I will use this logic in the future. I upvoted you for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you are using an alternation `|` but looking at the example data you can match 1 or more whitespaces after it instead.

If there is a match for the pattern, the group 1 value already contains 1 or more digits so you don't have to check for the `Value.length`

The pattern with the optional digits between parenthesis:

```
\b(\d+)\s+([a-zA-Z]{2,}-\d(?:\(\d+\))?\.\d+)\b
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/lnbFeB/1).

```
$CCI_ID = @(
"003417 AR-2.1"
"003425 AR-2.9"
"003392 AP-1.12"
"009012 APP-1(21).1"
)

[regex]::matches($CCI_ID, '\b(\d+)\s+([a-zA-Z]{2,}-\d(?:\(\d+\))?\.\d+)\b') |
        ForEach-Object {
            write-host $( 'CCI-' + $_.Groups[1].Value.trim() )
            write-host $_.Groups[2].Value.trim()
        }
```

Output

```
CCI-003417
AR-2.1
CCI-003425
AR-2.9
CCI-003392
AP-1.12
CCI-009012
APP-1(21).1
```